# Auto load all wallets when start up

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet

Every time I restart my `bitcoind`, all the wallets will need to be reloaded:

```
$ bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
  ""
]
$ bitcoin-cli loadwallet test01
$ bitcoin-cli listwallets
[
  "",
  "test01"
]
```

So I was wondering that is there any ways to auto load all the wallet under path `/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets` when startup? I have tried adding some config in bitcoin.config, but all didn't work for me:

```
wallet=/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets
wallet=/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/test01
wallet=1
```

bitcoin core version: v0.18.1

Comment: bitcoin-cli loadwallets doesn't work, but loadwallet does

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a systemd service, here's a way to auto load wallets using ExecStartPost.
This is what I added to my bitcoind.service file:

```
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c "sleep 60 && ls PATH_TO_YOUR_WALLETS_FOLDER -I database -I wallet.dat -I db.log | xargs -r -L 1 PATH_TO_YOUR_BITCON_CLI/bitcoin-cli loadwallet"
```

It waits 60 seconds after bitcoind starts, to give it a chance to load the block index first.
Then looks for wallet directories and loads each one using `bitcoin-cli loadwallet WALLET_NAME` command.

---

Alternatively, if you just want to load specific wallets on Bitcoin Core restart, add this to **bitcoin.conf** before restarting:

```
wallet=
wallet=wallet_name
wallet=another_wallet
```

Full path isn't required if you created the wallets in the default directory (aka **datadir**).
A wallet name is the name of the directory the corresponding wallet.dat is in.
The `wallet=` line is needed to also load the default wallet.
Make sure to add the lines in the **[test]** section if you're on testnet.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the wallet options multiple times.

I.e. specifying:

```
wallet=/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/wallet01
wallet=/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/wallet02
wallet=/home/ubuntu/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/wallet03
```

in your bitcoin.conf will load `wallet01`, `wallet02`, `wallet03`.

Comment: This doesn't works for me.

Comment: Hmm that's weird in this case I think you should post an issue on GIthub as that's the intended behavior (see the manpage).

Comment: I just tested out of curiosity and I can't reproduce, did you open an issue. If so could you point me to it ?

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that the count of wallets are a lot, we can't load them manually. I use a Python script which loads wallets:

```
import subprocess
import os

def load_wallets():
    wallets = os.listdir(wallets_dir)
    for wallet in wallets:
        try:
            x = subprocess.check_output('bitcoin-cli -testnet loadwallet ' + wallet, shell=True)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Some files may be in the wallets directory which are not wallet dirs and script will pass them inside `except` block.

> Change `-testnet` parameter if needed.